# css ::before attr() and unicode

Tags: html, css, unicode

I have a tag with an attribute containing an unicode representing an icon.
I would like to make a css rule to this tag ::before to set the content to the unicode.
But the unicode is printed and not interpreted.

CSS :

```
i::before
{
  content: attr(icon);
}
```

HTML :

```
<i icon='\f1e8'></i>
```

It is even possible ?

PS : It seems I'm forced to find a trick since I'm working over a Shadow DOM in which @font-face does not work and the icon attr will be data-binded...

Comment: The content is a string, printed as a string, just like -> \f1e8

Comment: Try to use decimal value of the hex, like `<i icon="&#404;">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use UTF-8 characters for use in html. Working example is below:

```css
i::before
{
  content: attr(icon);
}
```

```html
<i icon='&#xf1e8;'></i>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you ! Same answer as @dfsq, with the x it's even better !

Comment: It seems yes, so I can data-bind it to be icon="&#x{{code}}" and it runs perfectly !

Comment: Indeed, it does not seems to work when data-binded :/

Comment: did you try dfsq way?

Comment: How about using {{code}} and in that insert &#x with coding...?

Comment: What do you mean by "with coding" ?

Comment: I tried to do icon="{{ code }}" then inject "&#xf1e8;" as the code, but still printed...

Comment: I think your old code works \f1e8 :) icon="\{{code}}"

Comment: I can't make it works like this. But it never worked this way, even without data-binding...

Comment: NO, without data-binding it not work, but with data-binding it might work...try once.

Comment: Yes I tried, even with data-binding it's not working.

Comment: Ooops! So sorry to hear that! I think you should ask a new question and tag that Polymer....hope someone would help.....

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thank you for all the comments, have a nice day !