# Polymer data-bind an unicode

Tags: html, css, unicode, polymer

Further to this topic : [css ::before attr() and unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207774/css-before-attr-and-unicode/27208022).

I'm writing an element with Polymer and I would like to be able to data-bind an unicode into an attribute of an i tag that will be used in the attr() of a css rule content.

CSS :

```
i::before
{
  content: attr(icon);
}
```

HTML :

```
<i icon="&#xf1e8"></i>       // works
<i icon="&#x{{ code }}"></i> // does not works
```

For some reason, it's not working, the code is well data-binded but the unicode is printed as a string and not interpreted as my icon.

What is the good way to data-bind this kind of data ?

Answer (score 0):

Data-binding including '\u' before the code worked.

Exemple :

```
icon = "\uf1e8"
```

Data-binded into

```
<i icon="{{ icon }}"></i>
```